# При вызове startActivity приложение падает

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DB db;
SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
Cursor cursor;
ListView listView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();

    cursor = db.getAllData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_PREV_IMG, DB.COLUMN_HEADER, DB.COLUMN_SHORT_TEXT, DB.COLUMN_DATE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.prev_img, R.id.tvHeader, R.id.tvShortText, R.id.tvDate };

    sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(sca);

    ItemListener itemClickListener = new ItemListener();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

class ItemListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "" + id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DetailedActivity.EXTRA_ITEM_NO, (int) id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

код DetailedActivity

```
public class DetailedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final static String EXTRA_ITEM_NO = "extra item number";
DB db;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed);

    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.imgViewDetailed));
    TextView tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderDetailed);
    TextView tvLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLinkDetailed);
    TextView tvFullText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFullTextDetailed);

    long itemNo = (long) getIntent().getExtras().getInt(EXTRA_ITEM_NO);
    Log.d("myLogs", "getIntent " + itemNo);

    try {

        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();

        cursor = db.getOneRecord(itemNo);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            imgView.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(0));
            tvHeader.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            tvLink.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            tvFullText.setText(cursor.getString(3));
        }
        //cursor.close();
        //db.close();
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "sql exception");
    }
}
}
```

Ругается на строчку startActivity(intent);
02-29 14:41:48.606 8270-8270/ru.arcsinus.SalesBlast E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.arcsinus.SalesBlast.MainActivity$ItemListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:55)

Comment: А какая именно ошибка? Можно полный стектрейс?

Comment: @VAndrJ Извините. Студия почему-то не прописала информацию об Activity в manifest.

Comment: @РоманКавыршин, а студия этого делать и не должна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio почему-то забыла прописать в manifest информацию о новом Activity. Пришлось сделать это за неё

```
<activity 
  android:name=".DetailedActivity"
  android:label = "DetailedActivity">
</activity>
```

Может быть кому-то поможет.